# Friends Online Presence - Facebook SDK 3

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Is it possible to find my friends online presence ( online,away or error ) with Facebook SDK?

Using FQL I could do it like this:

```
   SELECT uid, name,pic_small,pic_big,online_presence FROM user
  WHERE online_presence IN ('active') AND uid IN
   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())order by name
```

But is there a way to do it in facebook SDK, may be using something like this:

```
  [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"some/end/point/that/I/am/missing"]
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have same issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being late to post it here... I had solved this issue myself, here is my solution:

```
- (void)getFriendsOnlinePresence
{

NSString* fql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,pic_square, name,online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ORDER BY name"];
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                fql1, @"q",
                                nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"fql"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                          if (error) {
                              NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                          } else {
                              NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                              }
                          }
//Notify via notification center
                      }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do it in FQL then getting it to work in the SDK is simply a matter of figuring out the right query. Your query

```
SELECT uid, name,pic_small,pic_big,online_presence FROM user
  WHERE online_presence IN ('active') AND uid IN
   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name
```

is executed as `graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid, name,pic_small,pic_big,online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active') AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name` basically `HTTP GET /fql?q=<QUERY>`

So I believe just need to set the path as `fql` in `requestForGraphPath`

```
FBRequest *fql = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"fql"];
[fql.parameters setObject:@"SELECT uid, name,pic_small,pic_big,online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active') "
                          @"AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name"
                   forKey:@"q"]
```

The latest documentation though shows examples with `startWithGraphPath` under the `FBRequestConnection`

```
NSString *query =
    @"SELECT uid, name,pic_small,pic_big,online_presence FROM user WHERE online_presence IN ('active') "
    @"AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) order by name";
    // Set up the query parameter
    NSDictionary *queryParam = @{ @"q": query };
    // Make the API request that uses FQL
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                                 parameters:queryParam
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
        }
    }];
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/